# Computational algorithm for limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I wonder if there is any computational algorithm to find the limit of a sequence, assuming it has, correct to a number of decimal places.
For example, the sequence
$a_n = \frac{3 - \frac{1}{n}}{7 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$
has limit $\frac{3}{7}$.
How to determine computationally, no algebra just calculating a_n, if I want to get an estimate of it, say correct to 3 decimal places?
If I use $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < 0.5 \times 10^{-3}$ as the stopping condition, I will get 0.419 as the answer.
I think the stopping condition is not good in general as it relies on the rate of convergence of the sequence.
Any idea to set the stopping condition in general when the limit is unknown?

Comment: Depending on what you’re up to, you might have a look at Richardson extrapolation, the epsilon algorithm, or other sequence acceleration techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: What about algorithm to turn it into a Laurentz series?

Answer (score 0):

No such algorithm exists, because you can't tell anything about the limit of a sequence from looking at only finitely many of its elements.

Comment: Got it, thanks!